# How can I request multiple images at once from gstatic.com? (Google Image's thumbnails)

Tags: google-image-search

I'm using Google Image's thumbnails as thumbnails for my website. The URL of the images are something like this: http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTf5yKQDRXOR3gy76ypWmEsT8-9BZUvLMWQIjH4tyyxLkHuhj3ZtJm19UhV

Is it possible to request multiple images with one request? I tried something like this: http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTf5yKQDRXOR3gy76ypWmEsT8-9BZUvLMWQIjH4tyyxLkHuhj3ZtJm19UhV+ANd9GcR_2HdbSQ2lEldjoJXIwfRfQz4BhWBta0skbDqkO_mivicivPR7oQDkag, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In URLs, '+' is a substitute for a space.

You can't do what you're asking. Assuming you could ask for more than one image, how would they be returned? It's a continuous stream, so your browser won't know where one ends and the next begins.

One request == one file.